# Поддержка emmet в jsx vs code

Tags: reactjs

Как сделать поддержку еммета в vscode в синтаксисе jsx

Comment: а зачем еммет? есть же npm run watch

Comment: чтобы удобно писать html разметку
https://i.ytimg.com/vi/KD06xpmiaPA/maxresdefault.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

нужно в Plain-text выбрать JavaScript React
http://prntscr.com/mdktam